# Need ember model to return array promise not object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js, ember-data, emblem.js

I am trying to return a array promise to my model so that I can loop through the results in my template. I need the contact products to return as an promise array and not a promise object.

Model :

```
App.ContactEditorRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function (params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        contact: this.store.find('contact', params.id),
    /*need this to return array not an object which is currently does*/
        contactproducts: this.store.find('contactproduct',params.id),
        products: this.store.find('product') 
    })
}
```

Template: (using emblem for markup)

```
each contactproduct in contactproducts
      p
        ' quantity
        contactproduct.quantity
        ' notes
        contactproduct.note
```

Comment: You're searching by id, it doesn't return a collection when you specify a resource id.  Why does it need to be a collection?

Comment: I need to be able to loop through the results. Each contact has 0 to many products stored in contact products

Comment: this might help you: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/models/finding-records/

Comment: if contact products is a hasMany on the contacts, why are you fetching it in the rsvp hash?  It should be a part of the contact model...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want it to be an array with the way you have your code currently structured, then you can do

```
contactproducts: this.store.find('contactproduct',params.id)
    .then(product => [product])
```

This is an approach to take when you want to do some additional processing on the result of a `find`, yet still return a promise as `model` is designed to do.

However, as another poster indicated this is probably not what you want to be doing. If contact products are a `hasMany` property of contacts, then they will already be there (or perhaps fetched for you based on `{async: true}`).

If contacts has no `hasMany('contactproduct')`, then you may need to fetch them yourself, but I doubt if contact products have the same id as contacts. If they do, they shouldn't. model IDs should be unique. Assuming contact products have a `belongsTo` pointing back to `contact` then you want to do this:

```
contactproducts: this.store.find('contactproduct', { contact: params.id })
```

which **will** return a (promise for) an array.

However, in general in such cases it's better to put the additional retrieval in the `afterModel` hook. That allows you keep your `model` nice and clean.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for the syntax with `contactproducts: this.store.find('contactproduct', { contact: params.id })` . The data design has contactproducts pulled out into a separate table because there is a quantity attribute for each contact to product relationship.

Comment: @KyleSnell side-note, you seem to be using a proxying controller (ObjectController) since you refer to `contactproducts` in the template and not `model.contactproducts`. this is deprecated behaviour and the explicit version is more maintainable.